# Conditional Value Subtraction on 1 table

Tags: math, db2, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

This is my first time asking question here so please let me know if I can provide anymore data to assist you assisting me :)

At the current moment, I have a table that resembles the following:
    
ID  ITEM  ADJUST_QTY  ADJUST_TYPE  INV_SOURCE&n bsp; INV_DEST  WAREHOUSE  VENDORASN

1   A12    100                  A                        NULL               ALLOC        1001               NULL
    
2   A12    50                    S                        NULL               ALLOC        1001               NULL

3   A12    100                  S                        NULL              UN-ALLOC   1001               12345

4   A12    50                    A                        NULL              UN-ALLOC   1001               12345

5   B12    100                  A                        ALLOC           UN-ALLOC   1002               NULL

6   B12    100                  A                        UN-ALLOC     ALLOC         1002               NULL

The output of my query should be:

ITEM  ADJUST_QTY  INV_SOURCE  INV_DEST  WAREHOUSE  VENDORASN

A12    50                    NULL               ALLOC        1001               NULL              (This is ID 1 - ID 2)

A12    -50                   NULL               UN-ALLOC  1001               12345             (This is ID 4 - ID 3)

B12    100                  ALLOC            UN-ALLOC  1002               NULL               (This is ID 5)

B12    100                  UN-ALLOC      ALLOC        1002               NULL               (This is ID 6)

ADJUST_TYPE A = Add and S = Subtract. I am trying to find the SUM(A) - SUM(S) where the ITEM, INV_SOURCE, INV_DEST, WAREHOUSE, and VENDORASN are the same. Currently, I am using a left join and group by to try to achieve this but I am not getting any results. I know there are records that meet my need but my query is not correct at this point.

I have the following query at the moment:

```
SELECT 
    I1.ITEM,
    SUM(I1.ADJUST_QTY)-SUM(I2.ADJUST_QTY) AS QUANTITY, 
    I1.INV_SOURCE, 
    I1.INV_DEST,
    I1.WAREHOUSE,
    I1.VENDORASN 
FROM    
    INV_ADJUSTMENT I1 
LEFT JOIN 
    INV_ADJUSTMENT I2 
ON (I2.ADJUST_TYPE='S' 
    AND I2.WAREHOUSE=I1.WAREHOUSE                                     
    AND I2.ITEM=I1.ITEM 
    AND I2.INV_SOURCE=I1.INV_SOURCE 
    AND I2.INV_DEST=I1.INV_DEST 
    AND I2.VENDORASN = I1.VENDORASN) 
WHERE I1.ADJUST_TYPE='A' 
GROUP BY 
    I1.ITEM,
    I1.INV_SOURCE,
    I1.INV_DEST,
    I1.WAREHOUSE,
    I1.VENDORASN, 
    I2.ITEM,
    I2.INV_SOURCE,
    I2.INV_DEST,
    I2.WAREHOUSE,
    I2.VENDORASN;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  ITEM, 
  INV_SOURCE, 
  INV_DEST, 
  WAREHOUSE, 
  VENDORASN, 
  SUM( ( if ( ADJUST_TYPE ='S', -ADJUST_QTY , ADJUST_QTY ) ) ) AS ADJUSTMENT
FROM INV_ADJUSTMENT
GROUP BY ITEM, INV_SOURCE, INV_DEST, WAREHOUSE, VENDORASN
```

Comment: Note I forgot to add. I am on DB2 at the moment. When I run the above statement, I get SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC==;DJUST_TYPE which corresponds to A syntax error was detected where the symbol "token". Not sure what's causing the issue since the column name is spelled correctly.

Comment: OP was tagged mysql so that's what I wrote for.  :)  I don't have access to DB2 to test nor do I have any significant experience with it.  Is your final production environment going to be DB2 or mysql?

Comment: Unfortunately, DB2. Our application is built for SQL but this certain customer uses DB2 and will not switch :(

Comment: Bummer.  Well, I'm sure you don't need a join but a group. Putting a conditional inside a function can be a little picky about how many sets of parens you add - in mysql :) - so I suspect that is the problem. But again, don't know DB2. You might want to retag the question.

Comment: Thanks. Made the edit. I'll mess around with what you have given and maybe try using Case. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you see if below query works. Add the remaining joins in the subquery.

```
SELECT l.ITEM,         
   l.ADJUST_QTY - (SELECT ADJUST_QTY 
              FROM INV_ADJUSTMENT x
              WHERE x.ITEM = l.ITEM
              LIMIT 1) total
FROM INV_ADJUSTMENT l Where l.ADJUST_TYPE = 'S';
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f5698/23)

Comment: Your fiddle gives *incorrect* answers compared to the desired results. Nor does it contain enough columns or rows to properly test when you get closer. Plus it is mySql, not DB2, although a portable answer is quite possible.  (Mine is *almost* portable)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overcomplicating the situation. Try this:

```
SELECT 
 I1.ITEM, 
 SUM(I1.ADJUST_QTY \* case I1.ADJUST_TYPE when 'S' then -1 else 1 end),
 I1.INV_SOURCE, 
 I1.INV_DEST,I1.WAREHOUSE,I1.VENDORASN 
FROM 
 INV_ADJUSTMENT I1 
GROUP BY 
 I1.ITEM,I1.INV_SOURCE,I1.INV_DEST,I1.WAREHOUSE,I1.VENDORASN;
```

Note I had to put a backslash (`\`) before the multiplication operator `*` in the `SUM()` otherwise I could not post the answer. Remove the backslash when testing the query.

Comment: Why does everyone write code to multiply by -1?  Computers can subtract from zero *much* faster.

Comment: @WarrenT - Is there any performance comparison we could look at?

Comment: Its basic understanding of CPU instructions. Write a loop to multiply int x = x * -1 a million times and another to subtract int y = 0 - y a million times. In C or such, you should see a substantial difference. In an SQL query like this, the overall impact would be insignificant.  So on one hand there is little point in worrying about it, on the other hand why shouldn't we (as a profession) habitually choose the simpler, more efficient option?

Comment: Though true enough, it can be a question of easy readability, particularly when adding complexity to a SQL statement. I ran the two forms in a SQLRPGLE module over a 1.9M row table on a small model 515 to see how much of a difference it made. For the (x = x * -1) form, the time averaged 51.031 seconds over three runs, and for (y = 0 - y), it averaged 46.325 seconds. The difference might not be significant enough to matter in most cases. The amount of compiled code behind SQL tends to overshadow the tiny code of the math. (BTW, the difference was also almost as small for simple math loops.)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you can group like this, then this calculation should be faster than multiplying.  (Why do people always do that?)  It also ignores any rows that are not 'A' or 'S'.  As long as that would be a rare event (if ever) then it should be faster to handle it in the case, rather than perform extra tests in a WHERE clause.

```
SELECT ITEM, 
       SUM(case ADJUST_TYPE 
             when 'A' then ADJUST_QTY 
             when 'S' then 0 - ADJUST_QTY
             else null 
          end) as tot_qty,
       INV_SOURCE, 
       INV_DEST,
       WAREHOUSE,
       VENDORASN 
  FROM INV_ADJUSTMENT 
  GROUP BY ITEM, INV_SOURCE, INV_DEST, WAREHOUSE, VENDORASN
```